# Mamp won't start apache (Windows 10)

Tags: php, windows, apache, windows-10, mamp

I've installed MAMP Pro on my Windows 10 Computer this week, and it worked fine until today. I've restarted my computer and immediately started MAMP Pro - this caused the MySQL server to start, but not Apache. Then, I restarted MAMP and no server was running, I've checked if any other Services were running on the MAMP port but there were none. I also changed the Ports in MAMP but it wasn't working either.

Why might this be happening?

Here are the Apache logs:

```
[Sat Oct 21 04:46:43 2017] [warn] pid file C:/MAMP/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:43 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:43 2017] [notice] Digest: done

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:44 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2e mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/7.1.5 

mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:44 2017] [notice] Server built: May  6 2016 10:19:53

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:44 2017] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5348

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:45 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:45 2017] [notice] Digest: done

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:46 2017] [notice] Child 5348: Child process is running

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:46 2017] [notice] Child 5348: Acquired the start mutex.

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:46 2017] [notice] Child 5348: Starting 64 worker threads.

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:46 2017] [notice] Child 5348: Starting thread to listen on port 443.

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:46 2017] [notice] Child 5348: Starting thread to listen on port 443.

[Sat Oct 21 04:46:46 2017] [notice] Child 5348: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Answer (score 18):

Do the following:
MAMP -> Preferences -> PHP. Change Standard Version 7.3.7 to 7.2.14. Start the servers. 
After success, you can return to Standard Version 7.3.7.

Comment: This indeed works, thanks! But when I return to version 7.3.7 after it successfully started apache..same thing happens, it won't start the apache server again. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and the only thing that worked for me to get the Apache server started again was to change the **PHP version** to **7.2.14** in the **Preferences** area of MAMP:

### `MAMP > Preferences... > PHP > Standard Version > 7.2.14`

**Note:** After I was able to get the Apache server started again, I tried to change the PHP version back to 7.3.7, but this broke the Apache server startup process again. The green dot would wink on, and then off. So I am leaving MAMP with PHP version 7.2.14 for now (since the version of PHP doesn't matter to me as long as it is 7.x and not 5.6.x).

Answer (score 0):

A problem might be that the port apache uses is blocked by something else I can't remember that port but you can easily look that up.

I think 
world wide publishing 
Usually uses that same port as apache so unrun that and see if it works.

I know you said you checked the ports but world wide publishing is always running by default. So I'd check that.